# Access Flask application from local network

Tags: python, flask, browser, ip, lan

I want to be able to run Flask on a LAN connection **without connection to the internet**. When running the flask application it starts and runs on host = 0.0.0.0:5000 but the site can't be reached from browsers going to 0.0.0.0:5000. Running with an internet connection to the network allows the site to show up. When communicating from another device on the same network sending a post to the Flask's ip and correct endpoint allows for a successful http post request with response when the network does not have internet.

The main function is shown here.

`if __name__ == "__main__": port = 5000 app.run(port = port,host = HOST, debug = True)`

Bottomline: **How do I run flask with a wifi connection that does not have internet to communicate with other devices on the network and show the site at 0.0.0.0:5000?** thanks

Answer (score 2):

its 127.0.0.1:5000 from your same pc or the local ip like 192.168.1.x from other pcs on the same lan, check your ip with ipconfig

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

127.0.0.1 is the localhost of your computer and does not require internet connections, besides, the address is used to establish an IP connection to the same machine or computer being used by the end-user. So it still can run even without the internet.